# How to output in a container different number formats picked from a form using the intl-tel-input library? JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, intl-tel-input

I have the HTML below which is using the library intl-tel-input. When a user inputs a phone number in the form I wanted to output in the output container the following things:

1. the word "Valid:" and then "true" on the right of the word valid if the phone number was inserted in the correct format.
2. the word "Raw local:" and on the right the raw local number from the form
3. The word "Local:" and on the right the local number from the form
4. The word "E164:" etc.
5. The word "International" etc.
6. The word "Country code:", etc.
7. The word "Country:" etc. For example if in the form it's china it will appear CN

This is what I tried but currently, it doesn't output anything. know this should be easy but am kinda new to javascript.

HTML:

```xhtml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/css/intlTelInput.css"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
      </head>  
      
      <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
          <div class="ml-auto">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="theme-button">
              <img src="light-theme-icon.svg" alt="Light theme" id="light-icon">
              <img src="dark-theme-icon.svg" alt="Dark theme" id="dark-icon">
            </button>

            <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="language-button">
              <img src="language-icon.svg" alt="Select language">
            </button>
          </div>
        </nav>
          
          <div class="container">
            <form id="login" onsubmit="process(event)">
                <p>Enter your phone number:</p>
                <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Verify" />
              </form>
            <div class="alert alert-info" style="display: none;"></div>
           </div>

        <!-- Output container -->
        <div id="output-container"></div>
      </body>



      <script>
        const phoneInputField = document.querySelector("#phone");
        const phoneInput = window.intlTelInput(phoneInputField, {
          utilsScript:
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/utils.js",
        });
    </script>
      
    <script>
    function process(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let phoneNumber = document.querySelector("#phone").value;
    let iti = window.intlTelInput(document.querySelector("#phone"));
    let isValid = iti.isValidNumber();

    let rawLocal = iti.getNumber(intlTelInputUtils.numberFormat.E164);
    let local = iti.getNumber(intlTelInputUtils.numberFormat.NATIONAL);
    let e164 = iti.getNumber(intlTelInputUtils.numberFormat.E164);
    let international = iti.getNumber(intlTelInputUtils.numberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);
    let countryCode = iti.getNumber(intlTelInputUtils.numberFormat.E164).slice(0, 2);
    let country = iti.getSelectedCountryData().iso2;

    // Output the results in the output container
    let outputContainer = document.querySelector("#output-container");
    outputContainer.innerHTML = `
    Valid: ${isValid}<br>
    Raw Local: ${rawLocal}<br>
    Local: ${local}<br>
    E164: ${e164}<br>
    International: ${international}<br>
    Country Code: ${countryCode}<br>
    Country: ${country}
    `;

  </script>
</html>
```

I tried the html written in the message above